# Getting timeout error for some cases in python 3.x

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, optimization, median

I am working on the Fraudulent Activity Notification problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fraudulent-activity-notifications/. And I have written the below code to 
solve this problem. This code runs fine for some of the test cases but fails for some of them, giving time out error. Can anyone help me in understanding how can i optimize
it and make it better?

```
def calculate_median(lists):    
    n = len(lists)
    lists.sort()
    if n % 2 == 0: 
        median1 = lists[n//2] 
        median2 = lists[n//2 - 1] 
        median = (median1 + median2)/2
    else: 
        median = lists[n//2] 
    return median


my_list = [2,3,4,2,3,6,8,4,5]
d=5
n = len(my_list)
count = 0
start= 0
end = d
for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
    if end < n:
        seg_list = my_list[start:end]
        check_val = my_list[end]
        median_val = calculate_median(seg_list)
        if check_val >= 2 *median_val:
            count = count +1 
        start = start + 1
        end = end + 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Extremely minor optimization: Since `seg_list` is always a fresh `list` (produced by slicing, which shallow copies), and doesn't need to be preserved in original order, `calculate_median` can replace `lists = sorted(lists)` with `lists.sort()` to sort in place, rather than creating a new sorted copy. Alternatively, you might use `collections.deque` with a `maxlen` to avoid the manual tracking of `start`/`end` with explicit slicing (though you'd need to use `sorted` in that case, since you can't sort a `deque` in place).

Comment: Used lists.sort(), still getting timed out error for some of the test cases.

Comment: I have been working on this since you added it, you cant afford to sort on every iteration you need to use a running mean average.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle How will I get median if I use running mean average?

Comment: @user15051990 sorry i meant running median average

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, I have posted answer below where I used besect_left and inosrt_left to solve this. This is one of the optimized way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used bisect_left and insort_left to solve this problem. This is one of the optimized way to do it.

```
from bisect import bisect_left, insort_left
count = 0
listD = sorted(my_list[:d])

def median():
   return listD[d//2] if d%2 == 1 else ((listD[d//2] + listD[d//2-1])/2)

for i in range(d,n):
   if my_list[i] >= 2*median(): 
      count += 1
   del listD[bisect_left(listD, my_list[i-d])]
   insort_left(listD, my_list[i])
print(count)
```

Comment: Very nice, i would never have reached such a solution

Comment: I also came across one article using this.

Comment: Yes to bisect module. It's a faster implementation of insert sort that can't be replaced with native python code.